# Read RSS feed with Biztalk

Tags: rss, biztalk

Is it possible to import the contents of an RSS feed with Biztalk?
I would like to import the RSS feed and send it to a Send port that put the content into a SQL Server database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start with an Xml Schema (XSD) that defines the RSS message - take a look at http://rss2schema.codeplex.com/ which defines an RSS 2.0 schema.

You would typically retrieve an RSS feed from a HTTP endpoint by issuing a HTTP GET request and the webserver would respond with the RSS content.

Unfortunately, the BizTalk HTTP Send Adapter (the thing that performs the HTTP request on your behalf) only supports the POST verb and I imagine you will find that the majority of websites won't let you retrieve an RSS feed by using POST.

There does appear to be a few options out there, including using a WCF-Custom Send Port (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/3d001f89-88e2-4c67-8a54-2ea5a5f7c064/). If this seems like a lot of work, you might simply want to consider writing a WCF Service or Web-Service which would perform the GET Request which you invoke from BizTalk.

Once you have the RSS response message, simply parse and write to SQL using a Send Port configured with the SQL Adapter (or WCF-SQL Adapter).

I imagine that the lack of HTTP GET in the BizTalk HTTP Adapter is why nsoftware wrote its RSS adapter....

Answer (score 0):

Since rss is basically an xml message, and BizTalk provides an HTTP protocol, it would seem reasonably simple.

- Create a receive location to retrieve the rss feed
- use an orchestration to load the content
- Create a send port to connect to sql server to write the content you retrieved.

It's not trivial, but doesn't seem too difficult